# How do I change a type of block in a specific area into another block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I change all blocks in a specific area around me (where I am currently standing) to another block? I tried using the `/setblock` command, but it only works for a single block.

For example, if I wanted to replace all of the grass with mycelium in a range of +/- 140 blocks in the X or Z directions, covering the entire Y range, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the fill command. You won't be able to do all **20 million blocks** in the 280*256*280 area that you want to do at once (that's a really huge amount), but you'll be able to do smaller segments:

```
/fill ~-20 ~-8 ~-20 ~20 ~8 ~20 mycelium 0 replace grass
```

Answer (score -1):

/clone x y z x y z x y z

The first two "xyz xyz" coordinates are the parameters of what you want to copy, the last "xyz" coordinates are where you want to paste it. And same problem as /fill you can only copy/replace so many blocks at a time. I tried to clone a whole village but it was too many blocks and wouldn't let me :D

Answer (score -1):

> `/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 <TileName> [dataValue]`

For that many blocks you might want to do it in multiple pieces rather than all at once.

Couldn't really understand the other answers so I thought I'd clarify a bit for anyone else who may need this question answered.

Comment: That's pretty much the same answer colorfusion already posted.

Comment: It posted for clarification because I had a hard time understanding and others might as well if they needed the same question answered and looked on here

Answer (score -1):

connect this command to a fast redstone clock:
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~x ~y ~z ~-x ~-y ~-z block 0 replace block2

substitute block with the block you want and block with the block you want replaced.